# What can you do with XMLHttpRequest and cannot with Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I know that as for 2020 the Fetch API can be considered a modern replacement for pretty much everything that was done with XMLHttpRequest.
But I wonder if there are still things that can only be done with XMLHttpRequest at this point.
Can XMLHttpRequest be completely dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can imagine couple reasons, why you can use `XMLHttpRequest`:

First, you don't want to use polyfills, but need to support old browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch

Second you need something specific from XMLHttpRequest, that fetch can’t do, like `upload` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload to track upload progress.

In other cases, use `fetch`.

Comment: The support is very good. Opera Mini does not support almost anything modern, so is out of the question, Internet Explorer with all versions still has 1.7% market share but is removed from the support of major websites and I think this figure will decrease. All the others would be around 2%, but maybe even this year the support will increase. So I will not use pollyfills. As for upload tracking, I think something can be done on the server side.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer if for 2 days someone else will not find something more significant.

Comment: Good point! 
I just want to mention that even if IE has low usage in general, for some organisations, which are sensitive for security (like banks for example), IE could have a bigger share. That's why for some web apps it could be required to support IE.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery depends on XMLHttpRequest (even if the latest version of jQuery does not any more, some previous versions do). Dropping support for it would cause all codebases using jQuery to break so no support can not be dropped.

Comment: I dropped jQuery a few years ago.

Comment: Good for you buddy.

Comment: What about the other 50,000 sites that still depend on it?

Comment: I do not dispute the importance of jQuery, it has been very useful for a long time, but for a new project it makes no sense. The context of the question refers to how we build projects in 2020.

Comment: Yeah thats where you are wrong. The context of the question was different

Comment: jQuery is a library. What uses XMLHttpRequest is included in the library, so it is obvious that you cannot get rid of XMLHttpRequest except by dropping the library, and the question was not about dropping jQuery but about dropping XMLHttpRequest.